# Какой трафик может нормально обрабатывать обычный аккаунт на сервере виртуального хостинга и на VPS?

Tags: сервер, хостинг, сравнение, трафик, скорость

Предположим на аккаунт сервера (сайт) будет приходить 100 тысяч запросов в минуту по 5 Кб, он их обрабатывает и отправляет обратно 5 Кб. Сами запросы сжаты zip, то есть нужно распаковать их, получить сырые данные около 50 Кб в формате JSON, содержащие 1000 строк, пробежать по ним со сравнением, далее запаковать обратно в zip и отправить клиенту.

Это получается грубо говоря 500 Мб в минуту входящих и исходящих данных.

Может ли какой-нибудь специалист подсказать, какая инфраструктура достаточна для этого трафика?

Comment: Я бы беспокоился не о трафике, а о процессоре. Задача «распаковать-сравнить-запаковать» выглядит довольно тяжёлой для полутора тысяч запросов в секунду

Comment: Согласен - процессор тоже имеет значение

Comment: Ну а в любом случае нужно просто брать и измерять, тянет ли конкретный сервер или не тянет — это зависит от слишком большого числа вещей, заранее не угадаете

Comment: Ну может у кого-то есть опыт работы с разными нагрузками и он посоветовал что-то?